# Different ways of declaring arrays and their names in Java

Tags: java, arrays, declaration

So you can declare an array in Java in two ways:

**1**.) The usual way:

```
int[] values = new int[3]; 
values[2] = 3;
```

**2**.) The easier way:

```
int[] values = {2,3,4};
```

For more dimensions:

```
int[][] numbers = {{2,5,6},{10,76,52}};
```

*So my questions are*:

- What is the name of technique *number 2*? How would I differenciate the two?
- How can I extend technique *number 2* to more that 2 dimensions?

Thank you for all your answers and I apologize if this question has been asked on SO already (in which case, kindly give me the link).

Comment: Your "more dimensions" is incorrect. re #2, if correct (don't forget the outer curly braces), perhaps initialize an array with literal values.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels How so?

Comment: Try putting it in a program and the compiler will complain as you're forgetting the outer braces: `int[][] numbers = {{2, 5, 6}, {10, 76, 52}}; ` Regarding "extending number 2", just keep nesting curly braces. Try it and you'll find the solution I'll bet.

Comment: in java multidimensional arrays are just the array of arrays. A 3 dimensinal array is just an array whose elements are two dimensional arrays. for example: int a[][]={{1,2},{3,4}} and int b={{4,5},{6,7}}. So a three dimensional array can be created as int c[][][]={a,b}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second example is incorrect as posted. I think you wanted something like,

```
int[][] numbers = { { 2, 5, 6 }, { 10, 76, 52 } };
```

which should explain that it's an array of arrays. To add another dimension might be done like,

```
int[][][] numbers = { { { 2, 5, 6 }, { 10, 76, 52 } } };
```

And you can print both methods with [`Arrays.deepToString(Object[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString-java.lang.Object:A-) like

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(numbers));
```